# choice between attribute and children cannot be represented. approximating

Tags: xml, relaxng

In my project where i have to deal with some of the .rng files, I am getting an error "choice between attribute and children cannot be represented. approximating", which I am not able to solve. The problem is coming in this piece of code:

```
       <element name="maintenance-mode">
          <choice>
             <group>
              <attribute name="on-install">
                <data type="boolean"/>
              </attribute>
              <attribute name="on-remove">
                <data type="boolean"/>
              </attribute>
            </group>
            <group>
              <optional>
                <attribute name="on-install">
                  <data type="boolean"/>
                </attribute>
              </optional>
              <optional>
                <attribute name="on-remove">
                  <data type="boolean"/>
                </attribute>
              </optional>
              <data type="boolean"/>
            </group>
          </choice>
        </element>
```

I am not able to find the root cause of the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I get the message you are reporting is if I try converting your Relax NG schema (rng) to an XML Schema (xsd) with [`trang`](http://www.thaiopensource.com/relaxng/trang-manual.html). So this suggest you are using `trang` (but not telling this in your question) or you are using something that uses `trang` behind the scenes, or the software you use is based on `trang`.

The warning you get is because Relax NG is able to represent a choice between an element and an attribute. Your declaration of `maintenance-mode` allows it to have the attributes `on-install` and `on-remove` or the children elements of the same name but not both the attributes and the elements. XML Schema cannot model this constrain so `trang` has to output an XML Schema that is *more general* (allows more) than the Relax NG schema it gets. The resulting schema allows an element to have the attributes **and** the child elements.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "bypass or remove this warning". If you just don't want to see it, you could redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null`. For instance, `trang in out 2> /dev/null`. (I do \*nix so if you run Windows, you'll have to find the equivalent.) If you want to prevent `trang` from generating the warning in the first place, then you have to change your Relax NG to: a) allow only `on-install/on-remove` as attributes, b) allow them only as elements, c) allow them as elements *and* as attributes at the same time. Any of these changes should make the warning go away.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and suggestions @Louis. From bypassing this warning I meant that is there any way I can change this schema so as to prevent the warning.

Comment: The last part of my previous comment ("If you want to prevent `trang` from generating the warning...") gives 3 possibilities.